# GAE which is better for global system contants?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

ok so this is a general question ... in my app on GAE I need to keep a 2 types of static data, parameters that could change like user names and passwords (for external services not my user database) so the best way is not to hard code them and keep them in the datastore so I can change them from the admin system settings panel. However, how about stuff that will NEVER change, like a list of countries for selectors in forms. Here are my options:

Option 1:

Keep them in the datastore under a dataUitls entity. However, this will have a toll on my datastore quotations.

Option 2:

Hard coded in a class. This will not affect my datastore quotations, and will serve much faster in a JSP loop as I dont have to wait for datastore transactions, however, this will substantially affect my memory and instances. Example is as follows

```
package system.Tools;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SystemConstants 
{
public static String[] tmp = {"String1","String2"};
public static List<String>Countries = get(tmp);

private static List<String> get(String[]countries)
{
    List<String>result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String tmp:countries)
    {
        result.add(tmp);
    }
    return result;
}

// getters and setters for whatever other parameters I have here

}
```

Both will work no doubt, but I need a professional opinion (preferably someone who has tried both) telling me which is a better practice for this particular situation.

Thanks alot guys !! Keep em coming !!

Comment: i just don't get how an array of countries names is even a memory concern?  20 bytes per name, 100 countries... 2000 bytes?  That can't be a concern?

Comment: I am talking about the concept ... scale that up ... Thats all

Answer (score 1):

Hard coded constants have far less processor overhead than Datastore queries and also use less memory.  The memory overhead of Datastore access classes and objects will exceed that of a fairly large number of hard coded constants.

The only possible advantage that Datastore may have, in an extreme case, is slightly less memory usage when you need only a small subset of lots of data.  A list of countries is not that extreme.

The best choice will depend on specific details of your situation.  Rather than speculate, measure and compare.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirement. If you believe your data will NEVER change, then no barrier to hardcode. Whenever you want to add multi language support, you may end up with lots of changes due to hardcoding.

Don't be too concerned about memeory usage for just a static variable. its negligible compared to other memory usages within you program.

Also there is a third way that you can use. 
write these into a .property file and bundle it with your program. at the startup u read the file and load values.

In Summary, Don't think alot about memory. If your list is in the DB, you have to load it into the memory before you use. Database solution is good if those are changeable via a GUI. property file based approach is efficient and easy to program.

Answer (score 1):

You have some options, depending of the case and the data:

**Harcode:** if the data is not changing at all and the structure is easy and it is not growing (more and more and...), it could be ok.

**Properties file:** if your data change from one environment to another, it could give you advantage to get the data in the a file. Change the file is easy from one environment to another, more than recompile.

**Json or similar:** if the data structure could change (new properties) or it is "complex", to have all in a json is more easy to manage. Parse using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or similar it is one or to lines of code if you have the DTOs/classes. And the maintenance is better than hardcode data.

**Database:** if the data is not changing is "static" to put in the database doesn't give you any advantage, IMO.

Of course, whatever you decide, you can parse/read in the start up of the server and write the data in the memory or memcached.